# SNS: Can't delete unsubscribed email subscriptions

Tags: amazon-sns

The subscription listing (`aws sns list-subscriptions-by-topic`; the UI, too) shows a "Deleted" for a subscription that was probably unsubscribed.

```
{
    "Subscriptions": [
        {
            "SubscriptionArn": "Deleted",
            "Owner": "326764833890",
            "Protocol": "email",
            "Endpoint": "aaa@bbb.com",
            "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:326764833890:my-sns"
        },
        {
            "SubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:326764833890:my-sns:65d23ee0-57e1-4ba5-86e7-2913bef8c9bf",
            "Owner": "326764833890",
            "Protocol": "email",
            "Endpoint": "ccc@ddd.com",
            "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:326764833890:my-sns"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, there's nothing to use to delete. When deleting via the UI, it shows an error complaining about the ARN being only one part rather than six.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's no way to remove these, however, creating a new subscription for the same endpoint will simply replace it (once confirmed).